# How to load application from pc to ipod touch

Tags: mac, ipod, objective-c

I need to install application which is on my mac PC.  My iPod software version is `1.1.5`.

Can any one help me to how to install.

Answer (score 2):

You need iPhone OS 2.0 or higher to install applications.  IIRC it's a paid upgrade, that you can purchase through iTunes.